# VSTS REST API to change security permissions on Release definition or Release definition environment

Tags: azure-devops, devops, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I cannot find any documentation referring to VSTS REST API to change security for Release Definition or Release Definition environment.

I am trying to create an automation script to create a Release definition which will accept user list as a parameter and assign limited permission on the Release Definition and Release Definition environment.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the REST API to change permission of release definition or release environment. I submit a user voice that you can vote. [REST API for release defintion or release enviornment](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17921152-rest-api-for-release-defintion-or-release-enviornm)

Comment: Is there any workaround? I looked around and found tfssecurity command line utility, but not sure if it works with VSO [documentation tfssecurity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#collection-level-permissions)

Comment: @AnkushGupta This tool is used for on premise TFS and it is in TFS installation path. You can try to capture the requests of release definition security change (change security > click save) via developer tool (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx), then you can simulate the request to achieve your requirement.

Comment: @AnkushGupta please did you solve it with the approach suggested by @starian-chen-msft? I need to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This doc was useful to me:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/master/docs/integrate/previous-apis/security/acls.md

And the API works for me, using TFS 2017 update 2, API version 3.2.

```
POST https://mytfsserver/mycollection/_apis/accesscontrollists/c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de
```

with body:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "inheritPermissions": true,  
      "token": "<your team project GUID>/406",
      "acesDictionary": {
        "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1217126478-2421225543-2840439466-2364649907-1-111749626-101504790-2465118485-2523779884": {
          "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1217126478-2421225543-2840439466-2364649907-1-111749626-101504790-2465118485-2523779884",
          "allow": 2071
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For environments you have to change the token to something like:
"your team project GUID/406/Environment/624"

406 is release id, 624 environment id

This query was useful to list all the entries in ReleaseManagement:

```
https://mytfsserver/mycollection/_apis/accesscontrollists/c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de
```

Play with security permissions on release and environments definitions and see what happens in the response.

Note: c788c23e-1b46-4162-8f5e-d7585343b5de = namespace id for release management

In order to create release definitions with the APIs I had to use the preview API so the **api-version** is set to **3.2-preview**.