# Set permissions for different namespaces in Azure DevOps using Rest API

Tags: permissions, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I use RestAPI to set permissions for Build definitions, Release definitions, git repo and team securities? When I was using TFS, I was able to do this using Tfsssecurity.exe tool.

Edited.
For example, I am trying to modify the project permissions of Contributors group. like Allow Contributors to rename team project etc.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg8NT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [Security API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security) page?
You probably need to manage group membership using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph).

The [Get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops) page lists the libraries you can use and how to authenticate.

Comment: There is a PowerShell module that wraps this api: 
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the REST API to change permission of release definition and git repo. Other contributors submit a user voice that you can vote [Set version control permissions by REST API](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365828/set-version-control-permissions-by-rest-api.html)

For details,please refer to these links:

[VSTS REST API to change security permissions on Release definition or Release definition environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989699/vsts-rest-api-to-change-security-permissions-on-release-definition-or-release-de)

[Use VSTS Rest API to set git repo permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411681/use-vsts-rest-api-to-set-git-repo-permissions)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Hugh, I actually need REST API for Azure DevOps.. I think above is for TFS on prem?

Comment: Hi,wonderfulworldwithcharity ,the above is about vsts, it is the old version of azure devops.This captured api was available in previous versions, but it is not available in today's version.This is my mistake.Apology for the inconvenience.